React Native App Transport Security
Имеется приложение на React Native (0.69, не Expo). Если вкраце, то при входе в приложение я запрашиваю адрес АПИ, к которому нужно подключиться и, если всё ок, то продолжаем работу с приложением.
Проблема вот в чём: в XCode нужно указать в ATS список доменов, с которыми может работать приложение. Но домены у меня не фиксированные. Завтра (условно) я продам права на пользование приложением другой компании, а они будут работать со своим бэкендом (бэкенд на 1с (мы просто копию им дадим)). В этом случае мне придется каждый раз вбивать новые домены и билдить/ выгладывать приложение в AppStore?
Как сделать ATS максимально универсальным и сильно ли критично, если вырубить его?
